# EditText to phone memory?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have found a very good solution to my problem on another post ([Save entered text in editText via button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658308/save-entered-text-in-edittext-via-button))

however when I implement this code, my application crashes. Any advice would be appreciated, the error I receive is that the "String or" in the method makeTag() is not used. Please have a look

```
private Button savenotebutton1;
private SharedPreferences savednotes;
private EditText editText1;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.x1);

    savenotebutton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savenotebutton1);
    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteEditText1);
    savednotes = getSharedPreferences("notes",MODE_PRIVATE);

    editText1.setText(savednotes.getString("tag", "Default Value")); //add this line

    savenotebutton1.setOnClickListener(saveButtonListener);
}

private void makeTag(String tag){
    String or = savednotes.getString(tag, null);
    SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = savednotes.edit();
    preferencesEditor.putString("tag",tag); //change this line to this
    preferencesEditor.commit();
}

public OnClickListener saveButtonListener = new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(editText1.getText().length()>0){
        makeTag(editText1.getText().toString());    

        ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText1.getWindowToken(),0);

        }
    }
};
```

}

Comment: please post your logcat error

Comment: try to change this  `String or = savednotes.getString(tag, " ");` into your makeTag

Comment: Process(1411): Sending signal. PID: 1411 SIG: 9
: W/dalvikvm(1451): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ae8ba8)
4: E/AndroidRuntime(1451): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
: E/AndroidRuntime(1451): Process: com.example.savingtext, PID: 1451
03-01 06:36:14.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1451): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.savingtext/com.example.savingtext.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class

Comment: post your `manifest.xml` file error is about you are not register your activity into `manifest.xml` file.

Comment: that was it! Thank you so much for a quick reply!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace this

```
 String or = savednotes.getString(tag, null);
```

With

```
 String or = savednotes.getString("tag", "Default Value")
```

Under your `makeTag()` function

**Update:** Error is about you are not register your activity into `manifest.xml` file.