# Save multiple EditText values using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to build an app where someone can fill in their personal data like their name, telephone number, Email...

For each field mentioned above, I created an `EditText`. Now my goal is to save the user's input using `SharedPreferences` so that he/she don't have to fill it up every time they reopen the app.

The codes I've found take care of saving the data for one `EditText` only ([Save entered text in editText via button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658308/save-entered-text-in-edittext-via-button)). How can I achieve that on multiple `EditText` fields?

This is my XML file below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Vul dit compleet in"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000066"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

  <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Naam: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000066"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>


    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edit_Naam"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000066"
        android:hint="Vul uw naam in"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Functie: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000066"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>


    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edit_Functie"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000066"
        android:hint="Vul uw functie in"/>

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Personeelsnummer "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000066"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>


    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edit_Plnr"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000066"
        android:hint="Vul uw plnr in"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email: " 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000066"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edit_Email"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" 
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000066"
        android:hint="NS mail"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Telefoon: "  
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000066"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/edit_Telefoon"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" 
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000066"
        android:hint="zonder +31"/>





    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_Opslaan"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edit_Bericht"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.03"
            android:background="#009CDE"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="Opslaan"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: The link in your question might show single key value for shared preferences, did you try doing it with multiple key values ? Can you please post the what you have done

Comment: I am a real Noob so i tried a lot of things. But i'm just strting to learn to make an app ;-)
So i hope you can fogive me that i can not tell what i tried already

Comment: Check the solution below. I have posted a answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to save each `EditText` value and retrieve them next time your `Activity` reloads. The code below is adapted from the link you mentioned in your question:

```
public class PersonalInformation extends Activity{

private SharedPreferences savedFields;
private Button saveButton;
private EditText editText1;
private EditText editText2;
// Add all your EditTexts...

// Upon creating your Activity, reload all the saved values.
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_save_button_id);
    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text_1_id);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text_2_id);
    // Keep adding all your EditTexts the same way...

    // "info" is just a tag name, use anything you like
    savedFields = getSharedPreferences("info", MODE_PRIVATE);

    // In case no value is already saved, use a Default Value
    editText1.setText(savednotes.getString("editText1", "Default Value 1"));
    editText2.setText(savednotes.getString("editText2", "Default Value 2"));

    // Save the changes upon button click
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(saveButtonListener);
}

public OnClickListener saveButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = savedFields.edit();
        if(editText1.getText().length() > 0) // Not empty
             preferencesEditor.putString("editText1", editText1.getText());
        if(editText2.getText().length() > 0) // Not empty
             preferencesEditor.putString("editText2", editText2.getText());
        // You can make a function so you woudn't have to repeat the same code for each EditText

        // At the end, save (commit) all the changes
        preferencesEditor.commit();
        }
    }
};
}
```

Comment: Thnak you I will try this one :-)

Comment: Thank you with some small adjustments this was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to store in shared preferences

```
   // MY_CONTAINER - a static String variable like: 
    //public static final String MY_CONTAINER  = "MyPrefsFile";
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_CONTAINER , MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
     editor.putString("edittext1", "value1"); // you can also use like this editor.putString("edittext1", ed1.getText().toString())
     editor.putString("edittext2", "value2");
editor.putString("edittext3", "value3");
editor.putString("edittext4", "value4");
editor.putString("edittext5", "value5");
     editor.commit();
```

To retrieve

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_CONTAINER, MODE_PRIVATE); 
  String edit1 = prefs.getString("edittext1");
  String edit2 = prefs.getString("edittext2");
  String edit3 = prefs.getString("edittext3");
  String edit4 = prefs.getString("edittext4");
  String edit5 = prefs.getString("edittext5");
```

Comment: Thank you I will also try this one